# Ansible - items list from a variable list defined from inventory hostname

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-inventory

I have a variable named "bonding" in my host_vars - this is a list of network interfaces to be aggregated into bond0 interface. These values are defined in the inventory, and they are correctly listed in my variables for each host.

```
production/
├── group_vars
│   └── ipbatch.yaml
├── hosts.yaml
└── host_vars
    ├── ipbatch1.yaml
    ├── ipbatch2.yaml
    └── ipbatch3.yaml
```

content for *production/host_vars/ipbatch3.yaml*  :

```
---
bonding:
  - eno3
  - eno4
```

checking this variable is correctly set :

```
tasks:
  - name: debug test - hostvars
    debug:
      var: hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```

output extract - looks correct :

```
        "ansible_virtualization_type": "kvm",
        "bonding": [
            "eno3",
            "eno4"
        ],
        "dns": true,
        "ftp": true,
```

Now, I want to use this variable in a role, this way :

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        interface_bond: "{{ ansible_interfaces | select('match','^bond[0-9]') | sort | list | first }}"
```

```
  roles:
    - role: network
      network_ifaces:
      - device: "{{ item }}"
        bondmaster: "{{ interface_bond }}"
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][bonding] | list }}"
```

Here is the problem : ansible says my item list is empty.
I'm trying to debug my variable request, this way :

```
    - debug:
        var: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][bonding] | list }}"
```

The output is an error message. However, the correct values are displayed in the error message :

```
fatal: [ipbatch2]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object has no element ['eno1']"}
fatal: [ipbatch1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object has no element ['eth0', 'eth1']"}
fatal: [ipbatch3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "ansible.vars.hostvars.HostVarsVars object has no element ['eno3', 'eno4']"}
```

What I have tried :

```
var: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][bonding] | list }}"
var: "{{ bonding }}"
var: "{{ bonding | list }}"
var: "{{ map('extract','hostvars[inventory_hostname]','bonding')| list }}"
var:  "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname] | map(attribute='bonding') | list }}"
var: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].bonding | list }}"
```

But the nearest output, even if in error, is the first line.

Expected result : the *with_items* statement should return a list of ethernet interfaces, as described in *host_vars* inventory files

Answer (score 0):

`bonding` is the name (as a string) of your key in your hash, not the name of a var you want to use as key. Moreover, `bonding` in your yaml structure is already a list that you access directly. There is not need to use the `list` filter in this case.

The correct syntax to create your loop is either one of:

- `with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['bonding'] }}"`
- `with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].bonding }}"`

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator for your answer. However, none of this solutions work, and they both output the same error :

TASK [debug] ***
ok: [ipbatch3] => {
    "<class 'list'>": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

TASK [network : network | setup nics] ***
fatal: [ipbatch3]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'item' is undefined"}

Comment: Maybe should I change the way I declare my variable in order to get a clean variable name ?

Comment: The way you include your role seems quite odd. Can you post your full playbook ? I this is included in the playbook `roles` section, it cannot work as expected. You'll need to use include role as a `tasks` instead. Consider also having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. From experience: you usually come-up with your own solution just trying to get down to a simple example to try to reproduce

Comment: Actually I have cut parts of my playbook to make it shorter. Isolated tasks are launched before my roles.
But this should work this way :

```
- hosts: ipbatch3
  become: true
  gather_facts: true
  roles:
    - role: network
      network_ifaces:
      - device: "{{ item }}"
        bondmaster: bond0
      with_items: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname].bonding }}"
```